# Как подсчитать количество совпадающих значений в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день, есть массив:

```
array(12) {
  [2]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "802344"
  [11]=>
  string(6) "802335"
  [12]=>
  string(6) "802335"
  [13]=>
  string(6) "802347"
}
```

надо подсчитать сколько раз совпадает значение в строке и вывести количество и сами значения следующим образом:

```
  [1]=>
    array(17) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(7) "802335"
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(27) "2"
    }
  [2]=>
    array(17) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(7) "802344"
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(27) "9"
    }
  [3]=>
    array(17) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(7) "802347"
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(27) "1"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть специально обученная функция

```
$ar1 = array_count_values($array);
array_walk($ar1, function(&$v, $k) { $v = [ 'id'=>$k, 'quantity'=>$v]; });
print_r($ar1);
```

Comment: да, было бы хорошо, очень признателен был бы ....сейчас прочитаю про функцию )))))

Comment: обновил ответ с преобразованием формата

Comment: и это помогло. Отзывчивые люди на этом ресурсе, обитают . Спасибо большое !!!очень выручил, дедлайн горит ..... сам бы еще тупил

Comment: рад, что получилось. удачи!